# Why does Satan choose Eastern Standard Time 12:00 AM to end the world?

Tags: plot-explanation, end-of-days

In [End of Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146675/), why does Satan choose **Eastern Standard Time** 12:00 AM of Jan 1, 2000 to end the world by using **Christina**?

[image]

Comment: Because it's Hollywood film. Why would US film use UTC or IST to confuse there audience.

Comment: But Hollywood is on the other side of the US with a time difference of three hours, so it's probably more about where the movie takes place than it's about Hollywood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ankit mentioned in the comments, it's probably just to avoid confusion.

But then again they could have used IST (i.e. time in Israel) and explain it in one short scene and two or three sentences.

However, there are more problems with this, not just a potentially confused audience:

The Israel Standard Time (IST) is at UTC+2, so the difference to the US would be 8 hours (UTC-6 to UTC+2). This would put the whole end of the world into broad daylight at around 4 pm, if it still plays in New York (why not *Megiddo* to bgin with?)? Lots of people around, everything bright, less dramatic candle light, etc.

And why the name *Christina*? That's probably just the authors, considering it's the female form of *Christian*, which would be an even more blatant choice – at least for an English speaking audience – I would have called her *Josepha* or *Jessie*.

Comment: The US spans several time zones with the normal time difference between the east and west coast being three hours, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about the time in the US as you do. I completely agree as far as the question goes though.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, correct, but keep in mind the movie plays on the east cost, so using EST as "local" time makes sense. Even if you consider the other 3 (or 4?) time zones, you won't  get any closer to midnight than that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the out of universe answer that EST was chosen because it's an American film, however, I think there's a better answer to be found in-universe:

- Satan needs to perform his ritual at "midnight."
- It's always "midnight" *somewhere,* if we consider time globally.
- The events of this film take place in New York City, which is in the Eastern Standard Timezone.

Logically, Satan needed to perform his ritual at midnight, Jan 1 2000 *local time,* wherever he happened to be when that time came.  As it happens, he was in New York, which means EST, so that's the midnight he needed to use.